# How can I add text over separate images in a slideshow

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideshow

I'm learning jQuery and I've been playing around with different slideshows, trying to add text and effects.

I've been using this codepen as a template but when I add text over the images it doesn't slide fluidly and just clutters up my slideshow and breaks it. I have three different images and want different quotes over each.

https://codepen.io/pawluczkowycz/pen/emymwa

```
 ``<div id="slideshow">
  <div id="frame">
    <img class="slide" src="http://placehold.it/350x150/ffffff/f0265b&text=1">
    <img class="slide" src="http://placehold.it/350x150/ffffff/47d1c0&text=2">
    <img class="slide" src="http://placehold.it/350x150/ffffff/006400&text=3">
  </div>
</div>
```

Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a container around the images, position it with `position: relative` then add an element that is `absolute`ly positioned in it that overlays your text.

```js
var $frame = $('#frame');
    
 setInterval( function() {
    var slides = $('.slide');
    slides.first().appendTo($frame);
}, 3000);
```

```css
body { background-color: #ddd;}
#slideshow {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  border-top: none;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 9px #222;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
#frame {
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.slide:first-child {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;  
}
.slide img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  max-width: 960px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.slide:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}
.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideshow">
  <div id="frame">
    <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/ffffff/f0265b&text=1">
      <p class="text">foo</p>
    </div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/ffffff/f0265b&text=2">
      <p class="text">foo</p>
    </div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/ffffff/f0265b&text=3">
      <p class="text">foo</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap images in a div that contains image (as background maybe) and captions.
Then slide the div instead of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```js
var $frame = $('#frame');
    
 setInterval( function() {
    var slides = $('.slide');
    slides.first().appendTo($frame);
}, 3000);
```

```css
body { background-color: #ddd;}
#slideshow {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  border-top: none;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 9px #222;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
#frame {
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.slide {
  position:relative;
}
.slide:first-child ,.slide > img{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.slide:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}

.slide > div {
  position:absolute;
  padding:10px;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  font-family:helvetica,tahome,serif;
  font-size:18px;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideshow">
  <div id="frame">
    <div class="slide" >
      <div>
        Eaxmple Text for Slide No.1
      </div>
     <img  src="http://placehold.it/350x150/ffffff/f0265b&text=1">
    </div>
    <div class="slide" >
      <div>
        Eaxmple Text for Slide No.2
      </div>
     <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/ffffff/47d1c0&text=2">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
      <div>
        Eaxmple Text for Slide No.3
      </div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/ffffff/006400&text=3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```